# mfc change the cursor of a dialog from another dialog

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog, cursor

I have an application which has two subdialogs. On pressing a button on one dialog I want the the cursor of the other dialog to be changed. Is there any method other than sending message to the window?

Comment: What's wrong with sending a message to the other dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the parent class of the dialog available through the constructor (m_pParent) and refer to members of the other dialogs there. You can declare a friend class in one dialog to make private members accessible from the other dialog and change the curser this way.